# Prestashop : what's the difference between fetch and display in Module

Tags: prestashop

I wonder what is the difference between this two methods in a Module Class : `fetch` and `display`.
Looking at the source code of different modules I see `fetch` with `renderWidget` and `display` with traditionnal hooks.

```php
class MyModule extends Module {

    //...

    public function hookdisplayTopColumn($params)
    {
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'foo' => 'bar',
        ));

            return $this->display(__FILE__, 'html.tpl');
    }

    //...

    public function renderWidget($hookName, array $configuration) {
        if (!$this->isCached($this->templateFile, $this->getCacheId('blockreassurance'))) {
            $this->context->smarty->assign($this->getWidgetVariables($hookName, $configuration));
        }

        return $this->fetch($this->templateFile, $this->getCacheId('blockreassurance'));
    }
}
```

thank you and good evening !!